# Solution Explorer Don't Show folders Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, tfs

I am working on an application though i have folder under solution but it didn't show any folder. How to show folder here is the snap. Here i have added code to source control but only shows solution and show 0 Projects with under solution file though i have eState-Management-Web folder in my mapping directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you ended up in this situation (did you remove the project from the solution?), but a folder isn't a project. For example a `.csproj` file is a C# project.

So right-click your solution, highlight the Add menu and choose "Existing Project...", then browse into the eState-Management-Web folder and select the `.csproj` that's present there.

Comment: No i didn't delete any of the project

Answer (score 0):

Try to restart Visual Studio. In some cases a missing folder can reappear that way